# If for a.e $t \in (0,T)$, $u_n(t,x) \to u(t,x)$ for a.e. $x \in \Omega$,is $u_n \to u$ a.e. in $(0,T)\times\Omega$?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

If for almost all $t\in (0,T)$, we have
$$u_n(t,x) \to u(t,x) \quad\text{a.e. $x \in \Omega$}$$
does this mean that
$$u_n \to u \quad\text{a.e. in $(0,T)\times\Omega$}?$$

Here $\Omega$ is an open domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a measure space $\mathcal{X} = (0,T) \times \Omega$, and the set $$
  U = \{ (t,x) \,:\, u_n(t,x) \not\to u(t,x) \} \text{,}
$$
where for almost all $t$ the slices $$
  U_t = \{x \,:\, u_n(t,x) \not\to u(t,x) \}
$$
have $\mu_{\Omega}(U_t) = 0$.

If $U$ is measurable, you can apply fubini's theorem (assuming that the measured on $(0,T)$ and $\Omega$ are $\sigma$-finite, which holds in particular if they're the usual lebesgue measures) and get $$
  \mu_{\mathcal{X}}(U) = \int_{(0,T)} \mu_{\Omega}(U_t) \,d\mu_{(0,T)}(t) = 0 \text{,}
$$
so in that case, yes, $u_n(t,x) \to u(t,x)$ a.e. in $(0,T) \times \Omega$.

I don't think you can weaken the measurability requirement on $U$. In particular, it's not sufficient for the measurability of $U$ that all $U_t$ are measurable. Even if you additionally had that all slices $U^x = \{ t \,:\, u_n(t,x) \not\to u(t,x) \}$ are measurable, $U$ wouldn't necessarily be measurable I believe.

Comment: Thanks. I think you meant $\mu_{\Omega}(U_t^c) = 0$ (complement)

Comment: @riem Yes, I was inconsistent about whether the sets contain the points where $u_n$ converges, or the points where it does not. Instead of sprinkling complements all over the place, I instead changed the definition of $U$, $U_t$ and $U^x$.

Comment: @fgp How does one check that $U$ is measurable? Is it possible to glean it from information about $u_n$?

Comment: @student Well, what do you know about the $u_n$?